# Orbiting sphere should cast spot light on central cube

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I'm writing a program that draws **a rotating cube (with texture)** in the middle of the screen followed by a small **yellow sphere that orbits around the cube**. The idea is to make the sphere as a spot light source that illuminates the cube.

**Here is the problem**: as you can see in the images below, I'm failing to achieve the spot light effect. It seems that the entire cube gets lighted:

[image] 
[image]

I'm setting `GL_SPOT_DIRECTION` to be the cube position. I didn't set surface normals because I'm struggling to understand how to compute them for the cube, and I'm not sure a simple graphic application like this really requires it.

I'm sharing the code below:

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "glwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    GLWidget gl_widget;
    gl_widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**GLWidget.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QImage>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);
    virtual ~GLWidget();

    void _draw_texture_cube(int w, int h);
    void _draw_light();

    /* OpenGL initialization, viewport resizing, and painting */

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL( int width, int height);

    /* enable the user to interact directly with the scene using the keyboard */

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

private:
    int _width;
    int _height;
    QImage* _img;
    GLuint  _texture;
    float xrot;
    float yrot;
    float zrot;
    bool _light_on;
    bool _must_rotate;
    bool _pause_light;
    GLfloat _light_pos[3];
    GLfloat _cube_pos[3];
    GLUquadricObj* _quadratic;

protected slots:
    void _tick();
};
```

**GLWidget.cpp**:

```
#include "GLWidget.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QTimer>

#include <cmath>

#define LIGHT_MOVEMENT_SPEED    20.0f           // Degrees per second
#define pi                      3.141592654f

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent)
: QGLWidget(parent), _img(NULL), _light_on(true), _must_rotate(true),
  _pause_light(false), _quadratic(NULL)
{
    _width = 0;
    _height = 0;
    _texture = 0;

    xrot = 0.f;
    yrot = 0.f;
    zrot = 0.f;

    // Set central cube position
    _cube_pos[0] = 0.0f;
    _cube_pos[1] = 0.0f;
    _cube_pos[2] = -7.0f;

    // Set light position
    _light_pos[0] = 0.5f;
    _light_pos[1] = 0.5f;
    _light_pos[2] = -7.0f;
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{
    if (_img)
        delete _img;

    glDeleteTextures(1, &_texture);
}

void GLWidget::_tick()
{
    update(); // triggers paintGL()

    QTimer::singleShot(33, this, SLOT(_tick()));
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    std::cout << "GLWidget::initializeGL" << std::endl;
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);       // Black Background

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    /* Load bitmap */

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
    glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    if (!_img)
    {
        std::cout << "GLWidget::paintGL: loading image" << std::endl;

        QImage tmp(":/crate.jpg");
        if (tmp.isNull())
        {
            std::cout << "GLWidget::paintGL: !!! Failed QImage #1" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        _img = new QImage(QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(tmp));
    }

    /* Convert bitmap into texture */

    // Create The Texture
    glGenTextures(1, &_texture);

    // Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, _texture);

    // Generate The Texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, _img->width(), _img->height(), 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _img->bits());

    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "GLWidget::paintGL: !!! Failed glTexImage2D" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    /* Setup lighting */

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);    //Smooth color shading

    // Light properties
    GLfloat AmbientLight[4]      = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
    GLfloat DiffuseLight[4]      = {0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0};      // color
    GLfloat SpecularLight[4]     = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};      // bright
    GLfloat SpecRef[]            = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};
    GLubyte Shine                = 60.0;

    //glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, AmbientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, SpecularLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, _light_pos);

    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, SpecRef);           // refletância do material
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, Shine);             // concentração do brilho
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, 0);
    //glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Sphere
    _quadratic = gluNewQuadric();               // Create A Pointer To The Quadric Object
    gluQuadricNormals(_quadratic, GLU_SMOOTH);  // Create Smooth Normals
    gluQuadricTexture(_quadratic, GL_TRUE);     // Create Texture Coords

    /* Start the timer */

    _tick();
}

/* Draw the central cube with texture
 */
void GLWidget::_draw_texture_cube(int w, int h)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(_cube_pos[0], _cube_pos[1], _cube_pos[2]);
    glRotatef ( xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef ( yrot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef ( zrot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  // Draw A Cube

        // Front Face
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);           glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, 0.0f);              glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, h);                 glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, h);              glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);

        // Back Face
        glTexCoord2f(w, 0.0f);              glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, h);                 glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, h);              glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);           glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Top Face
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, h);              glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);           glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, 0.0f);              glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, h);                 glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Bottom Face
        glTexCoord2f(w, h);                 glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, h);              glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);           glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, 0.0f);              glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

        // Right face
        glTexCoord2f(w, 0.0f);              glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, h);                 glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, _img->height()); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);           glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

        // Left Face
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);           glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, 0.0f);              glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(w, h);                 glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, h);              glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    if (_must_rotate)
    {
        xrot += 0.6f;
        yrot += 0.4f;
        zrot += 0.8f;
    }
}

/* Draw light source and light model (sphere)
 */
void GLWidget::_draw_light()
{
    if (_light_on)
    {
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);    // enable lights that we use
    }
    else
    {
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    }

    static float light_angle = 25.0f;
    if (!_pause_light)          // stop moving the light source
    {
        light_angle += LIGHT_MOVEMENT_SPEED * 0.1;
        if (light_angle > 360.0f)
            light_angle -= 360.0f;
    }

    /* Set light source position */

    _light_pos[0] = 4.0f * (float) cos(light_angle * pi / 180.0f);
    _light_pos[1] = 4.0f * (float) sin(light_angle * pi / 180.0f);
    _light_pos[2] = -7;
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, _light_pos);

    GLfloat SpotDir[] = {_cube_pos[0], _cube_pos[1], _cube_pos[2], 0.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, SpotDir);

    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 150.0);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 15.0);

    /* Set the light model position to be the same as the light source */

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(_light_pos[0], _light_pos[1], _light_pos[2]);
        glColor3ub(255, 255, 0);                // yellow
        gluSphere(_quadratic, 0.2f, 32, 32);    // draw sphere
    glPopMatrix();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer

    glMatrixMode   ( GL_MODELVIEW );    // Select The Model View Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                   // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

    /* Draw central cube */

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, _texture);       // Select Our Texture
    _draw_texture_cube(_img->width(), _img->height());
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);

    /* Draw light source and light model*/

    _draw_light();
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL( int w, int h)
{
    _width = w;
    _height = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    // Select The Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();               // Reset The Projection Matrix
    if (h == 0)                     // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
       gluPerspective ( 60, ( float ) w, 0.4, 500.0 );
    else
       gluPerspective ( 60, ( float ) w / ( float ) h, 0.4, 500.0 );

    glMatrixMode   ( GL_MODELVIEW );  // Select The Model View Matrix
    glLoadIdentity ( );    // Reset The Model View Matrix
    gluLookAt(0.0,  0.0, 2.0,   // eye
              0.0,  0.0, 0.0,   // center
              0.0,  1.0, 0.0);  // up
}

void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    switch (e->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_L:
            if (_light_on)
                _light_on = false;
            else
                _light_on = true;
        break;

        case Qt::Key_P:
            if (_pause_light)
                _pause_light = false;
            else
                _pause_light = true;
        break;

        case Qt::Key_R:
            if (_must_rotate)
               _must_rotate = false;
            else
               _must_rotate = true;
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

**Lighting.pro**:

```
QT += core gui opengl

SOURCES += \
    GLWidget.cpp \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    GLWidget.h

RESOURCES += \
    resource.qrc
```

What needs to be changed in this application in order to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I can't tell you what all you need to do to get it to work (gl spots are a headache for me too), but I can see one missing piece: the light position needs to be a 4-element array. If you put a 1.0 in _lightPosition[3], it creates a point light (what you want for spotlight), and a 0.0 creates a directional light. Also, I think the smallness of the cube (4 vertices) as well as no normals will be the root of the remaining issues. GL will try to interpolate the spotlight across the vertices, but if there are only 2 across a face, it will just shoot the light right between (or straddle) them.

Comment: I agree with Mark that you should implement normals.  Normals are one of the key inputs to pretty much every typical lighting equation used in modern 3d graphics.  As for how to compute them, since your box is aligned to the Euclidean axes in geometric space, so will the normals.  So, your normals will look like (1,0,0),(0,1,0), (0,0,1), and their negatives, depending on which neighbor face you are representing, before world transform.  You can duplicate the corner vertices so that you have three verts and three normals at the same geometric position (so 24 verts total for the box).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not specify any normals for your cube faces. As OpenGL is a state machine, it will use the default surface normal for all vertices, hence all of your faces. As the normal vector is crucial for the lighting, all of your faces will be lit almost identical (vertex postions still are different, but the effect is weak).

You should also be aware that the fixed function lighting of OpenGL is done per vertex. If you really want to see a good spotlight on the cuve, you would either need to tessalate it so more vertices are used where the lighting equation is actually evaluated, or use shaders for per-fragment lighting.